# Android Gridview is not showing images from assets folder

Tags: java, android, gridview, for-loop, assets

I have a specific problem which has not be answered yet on stackoverflow; I have images in the assets folder numbered like 0.jpg, 1.jpg, 2.jpg etc. Using a for loop I select three images from the asssets folder and I am trying to add these images to a gridview but the images are not showing. The activity starts up okay just no images!

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview_result);

        // Sets the Tag
        gridView.setTag(GRIDVIEW_TAG);

        /*
         * Adapt the image for the GridView format
         */
        imageAdapter = new ImageGridViewAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

        // Set the orientation to landscape
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        // Retrieve 3 images form the database which appear
        // similar
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            // System.out.println(Retrieval.distances[i][0]);
            image = Retrieval.distances[i][0];
            int num = (int) image;
            StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            sBuilder.append(num);
            String imageNum = sBuilder.toString();
            System.out.println(imageNum);

            String file = imageNum + ".jpg";

            try {
                // get input stream
                InputStream ims = getAssets().open(file);
                Log.i("ERROR_IMS", ims + "");
                // load image as Drawable
                Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, file);
                // set image to ImageView
                gridView.setBackground(d);
                Log.i("ERROR_d", d + "");
                Log.i("ERROR_gridview", gridView+"");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.e("I/O ERROR", "Failed when ...");
            }
        }
    }
```

I believe the issue is occurring in the try/catch. Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should get all images first and set it to your adapter.
     // set image to ImageView 
     gridView.setBackground(d);
doesn't affect to your grid items view.

A good tutorial for it: [guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

Comment: I have searched this resource a few times and I still cannot fix the problem, could you offer some code to point me in right direction?

Comment: Can you send me the full source code? I will help you on that. Thanks!

Comment: I actually got past this bit and managed to get it working, of all things however I am stuck on a simple for loop. If you can work out the issue, here is the link to that problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25714467/android-for-loop-populating-gridview-with-the-same-image